# Bazel doesn't find MSVC 2015 during TensorFlow installation

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I faced this issue while building Tensorflow from source on Windows 10. 
The problem is that Bazel can't find the path of MSVC 2015 Update 3. 
Here's the output:

> C:\tensorflow>bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
>   DEBUG: C:/users/maxim/_bazel_maxim/xv6zejqw/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/lib_cc_configure.bzl:115:5:
>   Auto-Configuration Warning: 'BAZEL_VC' is not set, start looking for the latest Visual C++ installed.
>   DEBUG: C:/users/maxim/_bazel_maxim/xv6zejqw/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/lib_cc_configure.bzl:115:5:
>   Auto-Configuration Warning: Looking for VS%VERSION%COMNTOOLS environment variables, eg. VS140COMNTOOLS
>   DEBUG: C:/users/maxim/_bazel_maxim/xv6zejqw/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/lib_cc_configure.bzl:115:5:
>   Auto-Configuration Warning: Looking for Visual C++ through registry
>   ERROR: Skipping '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package': error loading package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):
>           File "C:/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1447
>                   _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx)
>           File "C:/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1303, in _create_local_cuda_repository
>                   find_cc(repository_ctx)
>           File "C:/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 217, in find_cc
>                   _get_msvc_compiler(repository_ctx)
>           File "C:/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 153, in _get_msvc_compiler
>                   find_msvc_tool(repository_ctx, vc_path, "cl.exe")
>           File "C:/users/maxim/_bazel_maxim/xv6zejqw/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/windows_cc_configure.bzl", line 223, in find_msvc_tool
>                   _is_vs_2017(vc_path)
>           File "C:/users/maxim/_bazel_maxim/xv6zejqw/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/windows_cc_configure.bzl", line 183, in _is_vs_2017
>                   vc_path.find("2017")
>   type 'NoneType' has no method find(string)
>   WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
>   ERROR: error loading package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):
>           File "C:/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1447
>                   _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx)
>           File "C:/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1303, in _create_local_cuda_repository
>                   find_cc(repository_ctx)
>           File "C:/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 217, in find_cc
>                   _get_msvc_compiler(repository_ctx)
>           File "C:/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 153, in _get_msvc_compiler
>                   find_msvc_tool(repository_ctx, vc_path, "cl.exe")
>           File "C:/users/maxim/_bazel_maxim/xv6zejqw/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/windows_cc_configure.bzl", line 223, in find_msvc_tool
>                   _is_vs_2017(vc_path)
>           File "C:/users/maxim/_bazel_maxim/xv6zejqw/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/windows_cc_configure.bzl", line 183, in _is_vs_2017
>                   vc_path.find("2017")
>   type 'NoneType' has no method find(string)
>   INFO: Elapsed time: 1,361s
>   INFO: 0 processes.
>   FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
>       currently loading: tensorflow/tools/pip_package

This last test was with Bazel 0.15.0, but I also tried versions 0.21.0, 0.20.0, 0.18.0.

Is there anything I can do ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the `BAZEL_VC` or `BAZEL_VS` environment variable.

See this page for an example and explanation about the difference: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.21.0/install-compile-source.html#bootstrap-windows-bootstrap